# Are Vectors Orthogonal complement

Tags: linear-algebra

Let W be the subspace of $R^4$ spanned by (1,0,2,-1) and (3,-2,1,0)

is (1,1,1,1) in $W^{\perp}$

is (1,1,-1,-1) in $W^{\perp}$

Please show how to prove these questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1,1,1) is not belong to $ W^\perp$  because
$\forall a,b \in \Bbb R, (1,1,1,1)(a+3b,-2b,2a-b,-a) = a+3b-2b+2a-b-a=2a$

but (1,1,-1,-1 ) belongs to $ W^\perp$
since $\forall a,b \in \Bbb R, (1,1,-1,-1)(a+3b,-2b,2a-b,-a) = a+3b-2b-2a+b+a=0$

Comment: Hi if v =  (1,0,2,-1) and u =(3,-2,1,0) why would you add them to find orthogonality and what rule is this called. Thank you this is very helpful

Comment: if (1,1,1 )is in W^{\=perp} it must ortogonal to each of linear combination of basis of W ,

Comment: if (1,1,1 )is in W^{\=perp} then it must ortogonal to each of linear combination of basis of W ,(a+3b,-2b,2a-b,-a)=a(1,0,2,-1)+b(3,-2,1,0)

Comment: :) yourwelocme!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $\,W=Span\{w_1,w_2\}\,$ , then $\,v\in W^\perp\iff v\perp w_1\,\,\wedge\; v\perp w_2\,$

Answer (score 1):

Besides to @xaviermo2's answer, you can find a good basis for $W^{\bot}$ by finding all $w=(x,y,z,t)$ such that $$\langle w,u\rangle=x+2z-t=0\\\ \langle w,v\rangle=3x-2y+z=0 $$ where in $u=(1,0,2,-1),v=(3,-2,1,0)$ and then check for the options.

Comment: ;-) $\quad\ddot\smile \quad +1\quad$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The complement space is orthogonal to the subspace.